# Set two colors text in a single DataGridView Cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a data grid view in my C# Windows Application.
I need to change the color of the last 5 characters in a cell but i dont know how to do it.

I have this code in the CellPainting event but is not working:

```
private void dgvSorteados_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            int sector = 0;
            int.TryParse(dgvSorteados.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), out sector);
            if (sector == 3 && rdbSenete3.Checked)
            {
                if (dgvSorteados.Columns[1].Index == e.ColumnIndex && e.RowIndex >= 0)
                {
                    string bolillas = (String)e.Value;
                    string[] bolillasArray = bolillas.Split('-');
                    string bolillasMin = string.Join("-", bolillasArray.Take(12));
                    string bolillasResto = string.Join("-", bolillasArray.Skip(12));

                    using (Brush gridBrush = new SolidBrush(dgvSorteados.GridColor), backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor))
                    {
                        // Erase the cell.
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds);
                        // Draw the text content of the cell, ignoring alignment. 
                        e.Graphics.DrawString((String)bolillasMin, e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black, e.CellBounds.X + 2, e.CellBounds.Y + 2, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bolillasResto))
                        {
                            e.Graphics.DrawString("-" + (String)bolillasResto, e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Crimson, e.CellBounds.X + 2 + bolillasMin.Length, e.CellBounds.Y + 2, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
                        }
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This code shows the DataGridView without rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the background painting code by using the `e.PaintBackground` call. Also you have to draw the strings only when the `ContentForeGround` is being painted. Use the `e.PaintParts` to identify the painting operation. See my sample code for its usage. It needs tweaking but you'll get an idea.

Sample Code:

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.Value != null && e.Value.ToString().Length > 5 && e.ColumnIndex == InterestedColumnIndex)
    {
        if (!e.Handled)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected);
        }
        if ((e.PaintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground) != DataGridViewPaintParts.None)
        {
            string text = e.Value.ToString();
            string textPart1 = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 5);
            string textPart2 = text.Substring(text.Length - 5, 5);
            Size fullsize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text,e.CellStyle.Font);
            Size size1 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textPart1, e.CellStyle.Font);
            Size size2 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textPart2, e.CellStyle.Font);
            Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Location, e.CellBounds.Size);
            using (Brush cellForeBrush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.ForeColor))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(textPart1, e.CellStyle.Font, cellForeBrush, rect1);
            }
            rect1.X += (fullsize.Width - size2.Width);
            rect1.Width = e.CellBounds.Width;                    
            e.Graphics.DrawString(textPart2, e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Crimson, rect1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what i want, but the problem now is that the datagridview appears all dark grey and if i click on a row it appears.

Comment: @Phoenix_uy check whether you have set the foreground color same as grid background color

Comment: Where do i check that?